# PMDC Motor transfer function

Tags: dc-motor, analysis, transfer-function

I'm doing an analysis of a PMDC motor and I don't understand something about the transfer function.

I have the following equation: 
\$(K_t\frac{1}{((s* L_A) + R_A)})(V_I(s)-k_b\omega(s))= (s^2J_m+sb_m)\theta(s) \$ 
which solved for \$ \frac{\theta(s)}{V_I(s)}\$ gives the result:

\$\frac{K_t}{s((s* L_A) + R_A)(sJ_m+b_m)+K_tK_b)}\$

I wanted to ask, where did \$\omega(s)\$ go? I'm sure it should be out of the result, but I can't figure why.

Thank you.

EDIT: I forgot to mention this. The equation is taken from the transformations of the electrical and mechanical components of a PMDC motor.

\$I_A=(\frac{1}{((s* L_A) + R_A)})(V_I(s)-k_b\omega(s))\$ as the equation of the electrical part of the motor, with \$V_I\$ as the voltage input, \$k_b\omega(s)\$ as the EMF. \$L_A and R_A\$ are the electrical resistance and inductive impedance.

Then, \$K_t I_A=(s^2J_m+sb_m)\theta(s)\$ is the equation for the net torque of PMDC motors which combined with the one above gives the first equation.

I've been trying the think about it and it might be related to \$\omega(s)= \frac{\partial \theta(s)}{\partial t}\$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: It might help if you explained all the parts of the original equation or left a link.

Comment: I've added some explanation. I hope it is correct.

Comment: Rate of change of angle is frequency

Comment: Is there a difference between \$K_t\$ (numerator) and \$k_t\$ (denominator)?  Or are the both supposed to be \$K_t\$?

Comment: @Brad it's supposed to be the same. My fault.

Comment: @Andyaka isn't the rate of change of angular displacement angular velocity (speed)?

Comment: @Naeriel yes it is and there are 2pi radians in a circle hence one rev per second is an omega of 2pi/sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key to your problem is the equation \$\omega(s) = \frac{\partial\theta(s)}{\partial{t}}\$.  You need to re-write that in the Laplace domain:  \$\omega(s) = s\theta(s)\$.  Once you substitute that in for \$\omega(s)\$, the math works out.

Comment: I though so after giving it a closer look. Thank you for the answer.